# overload operator= with non class types

Tags: c++

Sorry for the probably daft question. I would like to overwrite the default mutator/accesor for a class variable (using the `=` operator instead of the usual `set/get` nomenclature though. I'd like some guidance in the possibility. The closest resource I found to my problem was [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), which gives me 50% of what I need.

Let us assume I have this class (this code isn't my actual need, but a more trivial example of what I am asking).

```
class IDCard {
    int id;
    int operator=(const int& n_id);    // This works for copying
};

/*
 * copy value of id out (no same value check)
 */
int& IDCard::operator=(const int& n_id) {
    id = n_id;
    return id;
}
```

Given `IDCard my_id`, I can do this: `my_id` = 10, but I would like to do this too: int i = `my_id`.

For this, am I able to overload something in the IDCard class to return a primitive on the `=` operator or will that only work for setting the class object?

I can't see many cases in which this could be useful as it will make code more ambiguous, but I was converting some python code which had overwritten their mutators and accessors so I wondered if C++ had a similar capability.

Comment: [operator int() const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a conversion operator to make `int i = my_id` work:

```
class IDCard {
    int id;
public:
    operator int() const { return id; }
};
```

However I'd strongly advise against it and recommend using a normal accessor method instead:

```
class IDCard {
private:
    int id_;
public:
    int id() const { return id_; }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize you could do that. I would also not advise doing this either, as it was a pain to read the python code that was essentially doing this (albeit with more complex calls happening in the background).